# Flutter: How to make flag emojis circular

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, material-design, emoji

I'm trying to make flag emojis circular. I've tried doing this using `ClipOval`:

```dart
ClipOval(child: Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you tried circle avatar?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this but unfortunately could not get it work well.

Comment: try this package shape_of_view_null_safe: ^2.0.0 ( https://pub.dev/packages/shape_of_view_null_safe )

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion @KumaresanJackie, unfortunately I'm finding that package hard to achieve what I need.

Comment: I don't think so, I think I ended up using https://github.com/hadi-codes/twemoji

Answer (score 0):

Use Container

```
   Center(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
        ),
        child: Text(
          "",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I'm not sure if this is working quite correctly - I'm also trying to get this to work for any flag that can be multi-colored (e.g. ️‍), so not sure if this would work in this case?

Comment: Just store flag data in a variable.

Comment: Also if this answer satisfies You then please click on right symbol so that Your Question considered as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
class CircledFlag extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircledFlag({
    Key? key,
    required this.flag,
    required this.radius,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String flag;
  final double radius;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: _FlagClipper(radius),
      child: Text(
        flag,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 3 * radius),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FlagClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  const _FlagClipper(this.radius);

  final double radius;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius));

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```